# Swift discover and connect bluetooth 4.0 device to iphone 11+

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I should develop an app that should discover and connect to a custom bluetooth 4.1 device.

I download some apps like "bluetooth scan" etc but none can see my device on iPhone 11 (and also tried on iPhone 8), but on iPhone 5 it's discoverable in bluetooth settings.
Why? (It isn't MFi)

However someone suggest to use external libraries for resolve my problem, but I need suggestions.
I've a project with the latest version of xCode and swift as target

Some code example will be very appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If it's showing up in bluetooth settings, that is likely a "classic" connection (typically audio). If you're scanning from an app, that typically would be BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy), also called "Bluetooth Smart." These are unrelated systems. There is extremely limited access to classic connections from apps. If you're trying to scan for audio devices, that's not possible from an app.

Comment: @RobNapier on iphone 5 i cen see it, on iphone 11 nope (always bt settings)

Comment: This sounds like a bug in your custom firmware. You're probably having trouble with phones that support more advanced Bluetooth features. I would first suspect that you're supporting BR (Basic Rate), but don't support EDR (Enhanced Data Rate), and maybe have trouble when EDR is requested. But since this is a custom device, and the fact that it's 4.1 (not not 4.2 or later), I would first suspect the device. If you're testing entirely with the settings panel, then you're just testing for audio connections, and "external libraries" etc have nothing to do with this. (There's no app involved)

Comment: In either case, you need to make sure you know whether you're working with a classic or BLE connection. If you're confusing them, then you're going to keep going down the wrong roads. You need to know what specific protocol and profile this device uses. You haven't said what it is. (It is possible for connected BLE devices to show up the setting panel; they won't have a "Forget device" option like audio/classic devices).

Comment: @RobNapier it's a device made custom by the company that I'm working right now, it's a CLASSIC bluetooth. This device works perfectly with my android app using old phones and latest phones. It's not BLE and it isn't audio/video but it's exchange data (for example like a rgb led controller)

Comment: So apps won't be able to see it at all. If it's not connecting to newer iOS phones, then I expect the firmware doesn't handle the negotiation for newer BT features (perhaps EDR). But it's not going to be an application issue. It's going to be on the firmware side.

Comment: @RobNapier how can be a firmware issue? if it's work with older iphone that has bluetooth 4.x, I expect new iPhone with bluetooth 5.x have retrocompatibility as written in the documentations. But, knowing iOs has it's "very particular" rules, can't exist a way to use the old libraries of the iPhone 5?

Comment: What you've described here has nothing to do with any libraries. If you're using an app, then you're not talking to Classic/BR/EDR. You said you couldn't discover these devices *in the setting panel.* If they do not show up in the settings panel, then the problem is in the device. If you're trying to scan from an app, then what matters is *only* BLE, which is completely independent. Firmware can absolutely fail to work with newer hardware. BT is a sprawling, complex mix of overlapping protocols, and some things "work" even if they violate the spec (and the break later).

Comment: But to go forward, the key thing is to edit your question to be very specific about what you're doing, and what you're seeing and what you expect to see. If you downloaded "bluetooth scan" (I don't know what app this is), and it couldn't discovder the device on an iPhone 11, did you then download the *same app* and it could discover the device on iPhone 5? Or did you do different tests and get different results? BT has a lot of pieces that look similar but are completely unrelated, so you have to be precise about what you're doing.

Comment: Most critically, what is generally called "Bluetooth" represents two unrelated protocols: one generally called BR/EDR or "Classic," and one called BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy). This is incredibly confusing to people. Core Bluetooth has almost no access to Classic Bluetooth (the tiny bit of access it got recently have doesn't apply to most devices). With MFi, there is *some* access to Classic, if you implement iAP2 (but it is still incredibly limited, and you can't scan for devices). So when you say it's a classic device, without MFi, then I wouldn't expect any app to see it.

Comment: @RobNapier thanks for the detailed reply! Well, in the control panel/bluetooth of the iPhone with the 5 i can see it, with iphone11 no. I tryied with the scan apps for see something more with iphone11 but i don't see my device

Comment: "in the control panel/bluetooth of the iPhone with the 5 i can see it, with iphone11 no." That sounds like a firmware problem. Since it's not involving your app at all, it can't be a library or app problem, so the only other place the bug could be is in iOS. It is absolutely possible for firmware to have bugs that prevent it being detected by newer iPhones. (I work with custom Bluetooth firmware every day; people really underestimate how many bugs firmware can have…) The fact that this is a custom device makes this even more likely. You need to speak with the firmware developers.

Comment: @RobNapier thank you a lot, unfortunately I think can't be updated that firmware and for that i asked you more times, however I'll contact them. Thanks Rob for your time

Answer (score 0):

`CoreBluetooth` framework should be enough to satisfy all your bluetooth needs.
Here is a very detailed guide I can recommend: https://punchthrough.com/core-bluetooth-basics/

Also, I would recommend to spend some time reading the basics of bluetooth architecture if needed, i.e. central, peripheral, services, etc.